# Zeppelin : Convert a pyspark.rdd.RDD to dataframe (pyspark dataframe)

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to convert a pyspark.rdd.RDD to dataframe. I have already done it in spark but now in Zeppelin it does not seem to work in the same way.

I used to convert my pyspark.rdd.RDD  in this way :

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pandas as pd


#comment if a SparkContext has already been created   
sc = SparkContext()

conf = {"es.resource" : "index/type", "es.nodes" : "ES_Serveur", "es.port" : "9200", "es.query" : "?q=*"}
rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD("org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.EsInputFormat","org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable", "org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.LinkedMapWritable", conf=conf)

#to allow the toDF methode
spark = SparkSession(sc)

df = rdd.toDF().toPandas()
```

And it works... in spark submit **BUT** not in Zeppelin.

I am wondering why.

I have some logs error but it is more than 1000 lines.. If you want I can give you theses logs.

If someone has an idea..
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution : in the configuration of Spark Interpreter (in Zeppelin), you need to change the **zeppelin.spark.useHiveContext** line in **false**. 
Nervertheless, I don't understant why the problem raises at the line where toDF methode is...